# Why does the sscanf %n format specifier have no effect on the return value?

Tags: c, scanf

The return value from the sscanf function below is 1, whether the *%n* specifier is there or not. Yet the value in the variable *n* changes (from 0 to 5 in this case), so why doesn't the function return 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int d = 0, n = 0;
    char *p = "10   foo bar";
    printf("%d\n", sscanf(p, " %d %n", &d, &n ) );
    printf("%d %d\n", d, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Seems to me like it's by design rather an issue with the code here. Is this because the *%n* cannot fail, since it's just counting characters read, it would be redundant to check it this way? Thank you, I'd love to understand what's going on here more.

Comment: Because the value isn't scanned from the input stream. The function returns the number of inputs successfully scanned.

Comment: C18 says: *"Execution of a %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution of the fscanf function."* It is a design decision.

Comment: If the scan does not reach the %n format specifier, the return value for the variable is -1.  (my recollection is hazy, it may be unchanged, so preload it with -1 before the call).  This could be considered "failure", but it is good information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sscanf(p, " %d %n", &d, &n )
```

%n (next) is the number of bytes read so far from the input buffer. It is an output parameter to indicate how far the input buffer has been read before sscanf function return. The sscanf return value is different, it indicates "the number of input items successfully matched".

You can think of `%n` (and the `int n` next param) as a secondary output (or return) value.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

> the number of characters consumed thus far from the input is stored through the next pointer.

---

Some examples for your case to see the effect of `%n` (next pointer):

```
int d = 0, n = 0;
// char *p = "100   foo bar";  // 100, 6    // read upto 6 chars, parse 100
// char *p = "100foo bar";     // 100, 3    // read upto 3 chars, parse 100
// char *p = "foo100 bar";     // 0, 0      // read 0 chars, fails to parse any int
char *p = "10   foo bar";      // 10, 5     // read 5 chars, parse 10

printf("%d\n", sscanf(p, " %d %n", &d, &n ) );

printf("%s\n", (p + n));       // "foo bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

From C99 (§7.19.6.2):

> Execution of a `%n` directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the
>   completion of execution of the `fscanf` function.